# rails passing parameters to callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, model-associations

I have two models

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :checklists
  attr_accessible :deadline
  after_update :update_checklist

class Checklist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  attr_accessible :content, :category
```

Basically, the 'department' model has a virtual attribute called 'deadline', and it is in type of date. The actual value of 'deadline' is stored in another model 'checklist', in format of string.

Every time when 'deadline' is updated, I would like to check if there is an entry in 'checklist', and create (if not yet) or update (if already has an entry).

I was thinking this way

```
def deadline=(deadline)
  @cl = Checklist.find_or_create_by_department_id_and_category(self.id, 'deadline')
  @cl.update_attributes(:content => deadline.to_s)
  @cl.save
end

def deadline
  @deadline = self.checklists.find_by_category('deadline')
  Date.parse(@deadline.to_s)
end
```

But the above virtual attribute is not working. 
When searching for the answer, I found on rails cast that callback will be a better solution  for this kind of situation. So I am trying to something like:

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :update_checklist

def update_checklist
  @cl = Checklist.find_or_create_by_department_id_and_category(self.id, 'deadline')
  @cl.update_attributes(:content => ???)
end
```

I am not sure how to pass the value to the callback.

Please help me with this design. what is the standard way to handle this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

update_checklist is a method of Department. So within update_checklist, you can access any Department attributes, just like `self.id`, `self.deadline` is what you want.

Comment: But the content is not stored in any attribute of department. It is a value from controller (a form value).

Comment: But you are using "deadline" as the content here: @cl.update_attributes(:content => deadline.to_s)